# Rounding Stored vs. On-the-Fly Values

Tags: excel, vba, floating-point, precision

Consider the average of four numbers {4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.3}, Dutch rounded to one decimal place.

The average of the four numbers is exactly 4.15; when using VBA's `Round` function it correctly returns 4.2.  However, if I give it the expression that calculates the average it rounds incorrectly: `Round((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3)/4, 1)` returns 4.1.  I can coax a correct
answer by doing something like `Round(Round((4.1 ...)/4), 5), 1)` so I suspect it has something to do with how results of expressions are stored.  I also tried multiplying each number by 10 then dividing by 40, but the rounding was still incorrect.

```
? (4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3)/4
 4.15 
? Round(4.15, 1)
 4.2 
? Round((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3)/4, 1)
 4.1
? Round(Round((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3)/4, 5), 1)
 4.2  
? Round((4.1*10 + 4.1*10 + 4.1*10 + 4.3*10)/40, 1)
 4.1
```

**Question:**  In Excel/VBA, what's the difference between being given a float directly and being given an expression that evaluates as a float?

Comment: @BigBen Nope, `Round` is correct (round towards even numbers).

Comment: Fine, as long as you're aware. Then you're dealing with floating-point error: `? (4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3)/4 = 4.15` returns `False`.

Comment: @BigBen I'm aware of floating-point error.  The question is how Excel can give 4.15 to the `Round` function and return the correct result, but not an expression that resolves to 4.15.  Because 4.15 can't be stored exactly either.  Or is it a compounded floating point error?

Comment: Makes sense.  I take it 4.15 is stored "just over" 4.15, but the expression is stored "just under" 4.15.  At least it looks that way in JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.educba.com/vba-round/. They use different algorithms

Comment: @Jon: The expression does not resolve to 4.15. In floating-point arithmetic, each operation produces a result that equals the real-number-arithmetic result rounded to the nearest representable value. When there are multiple operations involved, the various rounding errors may accumulate upward or downward. Rounding 4.15 to the nearest IEEE-754 binary64 value yields 4.1500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625. Doing the individual calculations in (4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3)/4 yields a final result of 4.14999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
? Round((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3) / 4, 1)
 4.1
```

This is because you are adding floating point numbers combined with the buggy `Round`.

You can trick those values to become true decimals by forcing that on only one factor or addend, and `Round` will round to even, for example:

```vb
? Round((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3) / CDec(4), 1)
 4.2
```

You can also use `Format`, which does true 4/5 rounding:

```vb
? CDbl(Format((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3) / 4, "0.0"))
 4.2
```

To overcome these quirks completely, you can use my rounding functions, here `RoundMid` which also does true 4/5 rounding:

```vb
? RoundMid((4.1 + 4.1 + 4.1 + 4.3) / 4, 1)
 4.2
```

```vb
' Rounds Value by 4/5 with count of decimals as specified with parameter NumDigitsAfterDecimal.
'
' Rounds to integer if NumDigitsAfterDecimal is zero.
'
' Rounds correctly Value until max/min value limited by a Scaling of 10
' raised to the power of (the number of decimals).
'
' Uses CDec() to prevent bit errors of reals.
'
' Execution time is about 1µs.
'
' 2018-02-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundMid( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Long, _
    Optional ByVal MidwayRoundingToEven As Boolean) _
    As Variant

    Dim Scaling     As Variant
    Dim Half        As Variant
    Dim ScaledValue As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant
    
    ' Only round if Value is numeric and ReturnValue can be different from zero.
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then
        ' Nothing to do.
        ReturnValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = 0 Then
        ' Nothing to round.
        ' Return Value as is.
        ReturnValue = Value
    Else
        Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
        
        If Scaling = 0 Then
            ' A very large value for NumDigitsAfterDecimal has minimized scaling.
            ' Return Value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        ElseIf MidwayRoundingToEven Then
            ' Banker's rounding.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ReturnValue = Round(Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                ' Very large values for NumDigitsAfterDecimal can cause an out-of-range error when dividing.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = Round(CDec(Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ReturnValue = Round(Value * Scaling) / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' Standard 4/5 rounding.
            ' Very large values for NumDigitsAfterDecimal can cause an out-of-range error when dividing.
            On Error Resume Next
            Half = CDec(0.5)
            If Value > 0 Then
                ScaledValue = Int(CDec(Value) * Scaling + Half)
            Else
                ScaledValue = -Int(-CDec(Value) * Scaling + Half)
            End If
            ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                ' Decimal overflow.
                ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                Half = CDbl(0.5)
                If Value > 0 Then
                    ScaledValue = Int(Value * Scaling + Half)
                Else
                    ScaledValue = -Int(-Value * Scaling + Half)
                End If
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
            End If
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Rounding failed because values are near one of the boundaries of type Double.
            ' Return value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        End If
    End If
    
    RoundMid = ReturnValue

End Function
```

Full code at [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).